# Java sql how to make executeBatch() insertion to return boolean

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-insert, bulkinsert

Assuming we have a Person class with setters and getters that pertain to its attributes of:

```
private int age
private String name
private String address
private double weight //lbs
private double height //cm
```

And then a list of them as such:

```
Person person1 = new Person(18, "Jack Harrs", "55 Albridge St", 155.20, 167.53)
Person person2 = new Person(53, "Toby Canes", "59 Albridge St", 193.43, 179.11)
Person person3 = new Person(24, "Dwayne Right", "74 W Saint St", 183.22, 183.87)
Person person4 = new Person(33, "Shelby Johnson", "99 Broad St", 123.50, 158.30)

List<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<>();
personsList.add(person1);
personsList.add(person2);
personsList.add(person3);
personsList.add(person4);
```

Currently I insert via `executeBatch()` as such:

```
Connection con = ... 

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO persons_table (AGE, NAME, ADDRESS, 
                                                            WEIGHT, HEIGHT) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

for( Person person : personsList ) {
  stmt.setInt(1, person.getAge());
  stmt.setString(2, person.getName());
  stmt.setString(3, person.getAddress());
  stmt.setDouble(4, person.getWeight());
  stmt.setDouble(5, person.getHeight());
  stmt.addBatch();
}

int[] results = stmt.executeBatch();
```

Thus, `int[] results` would look like [1,1,..] where 1 is a success and x other number would represent a failure. However, I would like to return either true or false depending on whether the operation was successful or not. I've tried just doing a `return true` at the end and not initializing an `int[]` array however I don't see how to account for a `return false` situation in the code?

Comment: You can't. It is a defined interface.  If the operation was not "successful", what does that mean?  An exception is raised?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `results` should be used to determine whether all of the batch statements were successful.  For example:

```
    ...
    int[] results = stmt.executeBatch();
    return isSuccess(results);
}

private void isSuccess(int[] batchUpdateResults) {
    Arrays.stream(batchUpdateResults).allMatch(updateCount -> updateCount == 1);
}
```

Note that this requires all of the batch statements to have updated a **single** record.  If any batch statement returns anything other than 1, then false would be returned.  So the definition of *success* might need to be clarified.

Also, it's not clear from the example code what would happen if an exception is thrown.  Would an exception be caught in the method and return false?

Comment: What is the usual definition of a value not = 1 for a mysql database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but each element of `results` indicates the update count for that that particular query.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
try {
  stmt.executeBatch();
  return true;
} catch (SQLException e) {
  return false;
}
```

`executeBatch()` will return an `int[]` only when all commands in a batch were successful, otherwise, an `SQLException` or `BatchUpdateException` (subclass of `SQLException`) is thrown.

[Reference to docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--)